# Depreciation Calculation

Tags: vb.net

My form is supposed to let someone choose between Straight Line depreciation and Double-Declining-Balance depreciation. Straight line, I've got figured out but for some reason I can't get Double-Decline to work. Essentially the user inputs the year, cost, and estimated life of the item and the program shows them the yearly depreciation of that item.

So if the item is from 2013, cost $1000, and has an expected life of 4 years I would want the output to look like:
Value at beginning of 2013: $1000
Ammount of depreciation during 2013: $500 (which is 50% of the cost)
Total depreciation at the end of 2013: $500

Value at beginning of 2014: $500 (cost - previous depreciation)
Ammount of depreciation during 2014: $250 (which is 50% of the new value)
Total depreciation at the end of 2014: $750 (which is the total depreciation from this year and the last)

Value at beginning of 2015: $250 (same as above)
Amount of depreciation during 2015: $125 (50% of the new value)
Total depreciation at the end of 2015: $857 (same as above)

etc. etc. etc.

so I'll attach just the piece of code that I feel is giving me the issue:

```
   Private Sub btnDouble_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDouble.Click
        lstResults.Items.Clear()
        lstResults.Items.Add("Description: " & txtItem.Text)
        lstResults.Items.Add("Year of Purchase: " & txtYear.Text)
        lstResults.Items.Add("Cost: " & FormatCurrency(txtCost.Text))
        lstResults.Items.Add("Estimated life: " & txtLife.Text)
        lstResults.Items.Add("Method of Depreciation: Double-Declining-Balance Method")
        lstResults.Items.Add(" ")
        doubleDecline(CInt(txtYear.Text), CInt(txtCost.Text), CInt(txtLife.Text))
    End Sub


    Sub doubleDecline(year As Integer, cost As Integer, life As Integer)
        Dim depreciation As Integer = cost * 0.5
        Dim totalDepreciation As Integer = depreciation
        While (cost > 0)
            lstResults.Items.Add("Value at Beginning of " & year & ": " & vbTab & vbTab & FormatCurrency(cost))
            lstResults.Items.Add("Ammount of depreciation during " & year & ": " & vbTab & FormatCurrency(depreciation))
            lstResults.Items.Add("Total depreciation at the end of " & year & ": " & vbTab & FormatCurrency(totalDepreciation))
            lstResults.Items.Add(" ")
            year += 1
            cost -= depreciation
            totalDepreciation += depreciation
        End While
    End Sub
```

For whatever reason, the depreciation stays the same every year and doesn't reduce by 50% every time and I have no idea what to do. Any help or direction is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You don't appear to be using the value of `life` in your calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your Depreciation outside of your While statement so it will always be what half of the starting cost is. Try something like this you will need to figure out how you want to stop your while statement because you will never get below 1 since you are using Integers, I would probably change your cost, depreciation and totalDepreciation to a Decimal,

```
Sub doubleDecline(year As Integer, cost As Integer, life As Integer)
    Dim depreciation As Integer = cost * 0.5
    Dim totalDepreciation As Integer = depreciation
    While (life > 0)
        lstResults.Items.Add("Value at Beginning of " & year & ": " & vbTab & vbTab & FormatCurrency(cost))
        lstResults.Items.Add("Ammount of depreciation during " & year & ": " & vbTab & FormatCurrency(depreciation))
        lstResults.Items.Add("Total depreciation at the end of " & year & ": " & vbTab & FormatCurrency(totalDepreciation))
        lstResults.Items.Add(" ")
        year += 1
        life -=1
        cost -= depreciation
        depreciation = cost * 0.5 'Note calculation of your depreciation here
        totalDepreciation += depreciation
    End While
End Sub
```

See if this Modification works for you.

```
Sub doubleDecline(year As Integer, cost As Double, life As Integer)
    Dim depreciation As Double = cost * 0.5
    Dim totalDepreciation As Double = depreciation
    While (cost > 0)
        lstResults.Items.Add("Value at Beginning of " & year & ": " & vbTab & vbTab & FormatCurrency(cost))
        lstResults.Items.Add("Ammount of depreciation during " & year & ": " & vbTab & FormatCurrency(depreciation))
        lstResults.Items.Add("Total depreciation at the end of " & year & ": " & vbTab & FormatCurrency(totalDepreciation))
        lstResults.Items.Add(" ")
        year += 1
        life -= 1
        cost -= depreciation
        cost = Math.Round(cost, 2)
        depreciation = cost * 0.5 'Note calculation of your depreciation here
        totalDepreciation += depreciation
    End While
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: You should also bring the life into account.

Comment: @varocarbas I know, I was just pointing out his mistake that is why I stated that he should determine how he wants to stop the loop.

Comment: You are right, good point: it has to account for it not only because of being the expected behaviour (not going beyond the maximum number of years), but because otherwise this loop might not end.

Comment: Well the program is supposed to end when the Value of the item reaches $0. Also, I added in the depreciation = cost * 0.5 and changed all the values to double instead of int and now it freezes when I run it. So frustrating! Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @EvanLemmons Cost will never reach zero, you will need to set a threshold of .01 or something similiar

Comment: @EvanLemmons I added another example, using cost, plus rounding to two decimals using math.round

Comment: that did it! I took out Console.ReadLine() and it still works, what exactly does that piece of code do? Also thank you so much!

Comment: @EvanLemmons  I was using a console application to test, console.readline keeps the console window from closing  I just forgot to remove it.